# В чём смысл данного кода?

Tags: c

```c
int main() {
  char stroka[100];
  puts("BBEDITE STROKU!");
  gets(stroka);
  int dlina = strlen(stroka);
  char * ptr = 0;
  int i = 0;

  do {
    if (stroka[i] >= '0' && stroka[i] <= '9') {
      if (!ptr) {
        ptr = & stroka[i];
      }
    } else
    if (ptr) {
      stroka[i] = '\0';
      cout << ptr << endl;
      ptr = 0;
    }
    i++;
  } while (stroka[i] != '\0');
  if (ptr) cout << ptr << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Можете объяснить как работает(в особенности [`if(!ptr)` и `if(ptr)`]

```c
if (stroka[i] >= '0' && stroka[i] <= '9') {
  if (!ptr) {
    ptr = & stroka[i];
  }
} else
if (ptr) {
  stroka[i] = '\0';
  cout << ptr << endl;
  ptr = 0;
}
```

Comment: Считать строку и вывести все числа из неё по одному на строке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if(!ptr) — истина когда ptr равен нулю. Ветка будет пропущена если ptr присвоено какое либо значение.

if(ptr) — истина, если до этого переменной присвоено какое либо значение.